# Insulating basement ceiling

Tags: insulation, basement

My basement is currently completely unfinished. Having gone through my first winter in the home (Alberta, Canada), the floor is obviously quite cold!

As a cost effective way to keep the cold in the basement, **I was thinking of using something like RockWool Safe'N'Sound in the ceiling**, as I will eventually be finishing the basement into a theatre room, bedroom, bathroom, etc. and will want the sound-proofing anyway. However, as this product does not officially have an R-value, **can I assume it would still be effective at separating the cold basement from the warm upstairs living area?**

I do not intend to insulate the basement walls probably until the summer of 2022 (when I intend to frame and do electrical etc.).

Comment: It's really a matter of prerogative. If you plan do do that anyway, try it and see. Rock wool is about R3 per inch. I think getting the walls insulated is where you'll see the most benefit, though. That's where you're losing heat from the building envelope.

Comment: Maybe a search for "ubakus" here in DIY would help.